# Why is an existing JavaScript function not found generating Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet, webpacker

The error:

```
readyException.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: editMap is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (edit:190)
    at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
    at process (deferred.js:139)
```

The page from Chrome Source (`popupText` is generated with Rails):

```
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var popupText = "&ge;1908<br>Benefit  St<br>&le;1908<br>Fountain Ave";
    $(document).ready(function() {
       editMap(popupText);
    });    
  </script>
```

A few relevant lines of `application.js` from Chrome Sources

```js
function editMap(popupText) {
  if (laMap != undefined) {
    laMap.remove();
  }
  showMap(popupText)
  var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
```

Trying to move an app to Rails 6 and webpacker.

Comment: Is it  declared inside an outer function such as  `$(document).ready(function() {..` ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I looked into all the Rails render to make sure I haven't included anything elsewhere. And I looked again through the main .js file being used.

Comment: If I put the entire .js file in a Rails aprtial and load it via render, the page works

Comment: @charlietfl I get that something like that is happening. But it is in the application.js file. Is there a way to check for the the scope of the functions? I think it's more a webpack problem than Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack does not expose your JavaScript to the global scope; every file is treated as a module, which, in practice, is a function with its own scope. To expose a particular reference to the global scope, you can assign it to the `window` object, e.g., `window.editMap = editMap`, from within the module.

Comment: Thank you again. Maybe someday I'll understand JavaScript better.